# How to show top n lines of grouped line plots in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series

consider data below( from )

### read in data set (tolerance data from ALDA book)

```
tolerance <-  read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/alda/data/tolerance1_pp.txt")
 
 ## change id and male to factor variables
 tolerance <- within(tolerance, {
   id <- factor(id)
   male <- factor(male, levels = 0:1, labels = c("female", "male"))
 })
 
 ## view the first few rows of the dataset
 head(tolerance)

  id age tolerance   male exposure time
1  9  11      2.23 female     1.54    0
2  9  12      1.79 female     1.54    1
3  9  13      1.90 female     1.54    2
4  9  14      2.12 female     1.54    3
5  9  15      2.66 female     1.54    4
6 45  11      1.12   male     1.16    0
```

I will have a time series plot as below,

```
ggplot(data = tolerance, aes(x = time, y = tolerance, group = id, color= id)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point()
```

[image]

I do not want ALL the lines, but only top three lines ( representing most frequent id s in each time point )

I tried `top_n(3,tolerance)` but it does not give three top lines . it gives three top points not surprisingly.

any idea how to get to this?

Comment: How can you have a top line per time point? Do you mean the top three points per time point? Or the lines where the 3 means between the previous and next point are highest? Then you are going to have non-continuous lines...

Comment: But if you look at the top three points at time = 0, then only the red one is still in the top three at time = 1 so the blue and green points wouldn't have anything to draw a line to at time = 1. Similarly, if you look at the top 3 points when time = 1, the yellow-green and purple points would be making their first appearance, so wouldn't have any lines coming in to them. Furthermore, the yellow-green point is no longer in the top three at time = 2, so how can you draw a line if you only have a single point for it at t = 1?

Comment: great point to consider! yes so not all time points have same top three ids. so I want the top n number of lines suh that they cover top three for all time points. to maybe mute them in gray and then color top three ids for each of the time points. at least that way the plot will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. First create the mean of tolerance , then filter the top 3 mean tolerance and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

tolerance %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(group_mean = mean(tolerance, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(group_mean, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(cur_group_id()<=3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = tolerance, group = id, color= id)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]